# How to keep rows that matches certain pattern

Tags: filter, row

I guess this is a very basic question, any help would be highly appreciated, though. I need to keep only rows that match a certain pattern eg. from **Ballen *et al*** 2019:

```
| probeset_id   | Runner886     | Runner886     | A_batizocoi_K9484     | A_batizocoi_K9484     | A_stenosperma_V10309  | A_stenosperma_V10309  |
|-------------- |-----------    |-----------    |-------------------    |-------------------    |---------------------- |---------------------- |
| AX-123373785  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207617  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207618  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207619  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207620  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207621  | BB            | BB            | AB                    | AB                    | NoCall                | AB                    |
| AX-147207622  | BB            | BB            | AB                    | AB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207623  | NoCall        | NoCall        | NoCall                | AB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207624  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207625  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | NoCall                | NoCall                | AA                    |
| AX-147207626  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207627  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | AB                    | AB                    |
| AX-147207628  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | AB                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207629  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207630  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207631  | AB            | AB            | BB                    | BB                    | AB                    | AB                    |
| AX-147207632  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207633  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207634  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207635  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207636  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207637  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207638  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207639  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207640  | AB            | AB            | BB                    | BB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207641  | AB            | AB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207642  | AA            | NoCall        | AA                    | NoCall                | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207643  | AA            | AA            | BB                    | BB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207644  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
```

From this, I would need to keep the row that has a different pattern (AA, BB or AB) only in column "A. batizocoi" and the same pattern for the rest of the columns (AA, BB or AB).

Comment: Is this in excel, or programatically? Can you give a little more information on where you're trying to achieve this?

Comment: Hi MadaManu, thank you for your interest in my question. Started with UNIX but the command is generating empty output files, the command is: egrep "^\S+\tAA\tAA\tBB\tBB\tAA\tAA" data.frame_file.txt >> filtered_data.frame_file

Comment: So what is your expected output given the data that you linked there. Also, it would help if you'd paste the data as code or something in the question itself instead of using screenshots.

Comment: I'm sorry about the data set fragment, thought it was helpful. The expected output is a filtered text file with probesets (markers) that match the following criteria: A. batizocoi-characteristic markers: A. batizocoi ≠ (A. stenosperma = A. hypogaea).

Comment: So you're expecting only column A.batizocoi to be different than the rest of the row. Any other row is dropped, right? E.g: rows with all BB and A.batizocoi has AA is kept, but rows that have some AB and some AA but A.batizocoi has AA is removed.

Comment: Also, there's two A.batizocoi columns... which one is used? Also two stenosperma... but no hypogaea as you mention in previous comment.

Comment: There are two columns of each specie as they are biological replicates, both are used. I'm sorry about A. hypogaea label, it's the same as Runner (commercial variety)

Comment: You still don't answer my question. If you have 2 different values of batizocoi (AA                    | NoCall  ) which one am I looking for to be different in the row? Do you want the whole row to have AA or do you want the whole row to be NoCall?

Comment: I'm sorry MadaManu, I edited my comment but it was not recorded. In case both columns do not match, I don't want to keep it, so if there is AA/tNoCall or any mismatching (between the replicates columns) it should be dropped. Also, as I mentioned above, the script egrep "^\S+\tAA\tAA\tBB\tBB\tAA\tAA" data.frame_file.txt >> filtered_data.frame_file is giving empty output files, do you know what's the problem? that command is pretty much what I need. Thank you very much,again.